# returning string instead or returning the ModelView is not working in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

i have tried to write an upload option in my web application following mentioned is my code

```
@RequestMapping( value="/group/import/upload", method=RequestMethod.GET )
    public String GroupImportInfo( Model model )
    {
        System.out.println("in controller");
        return "upload-File-import";
    }
```

i have a upload-File-import.jsp file, but when i try to access that page am getting an exception saying..

```
type Status report
message /corept/WEB-INF/views/upload-File-import.jsp
description The requested resource (/corept/WEB-INF/views/upload-File-import.jsp) is not available.
JBoss Web/7.0.13.Final
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You say you have an `upload-File-import.jsp`. But does it live where JBoss expect it, meaning in `/corept/WEB-INF/views/upload-File-import.jsp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the ViewResolver is unable to locate the view. Hence, I suggest you to check configuration of the ViewResolver bean's **prefix** property(in the spring-servlet-config.xml) if it is matching the path of the requested view.
Apart from that I dont see any issue with your code.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for you help!!! i have missed adding the new view in tiles.xml file, i have done it now